# Send long value with NameValuePair in Android

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to connect to server through a web-service. In this web service, i'm passing list of namevaluepairs. one of my parameters is long but namevaluepair only accepts (String,String) parameters. this is my code.

```
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs =new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name3));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("difficulty", hold_now));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("score", numberAsString));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("response_time", elapsedMillis));
```

the error show this:
BasicNameValuePair (String,java.lang.String)in BasicNameValuePair cannot be applied to (String,long)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing your **"response_time"** as long in value.

Consider passing it like `String` as below :

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("response_time", String.valueOf(elapsedMillis))); // elapsedMillis possibly can be long from looking at your code
```